# Android BLE set multiple notifications for multiple ble devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Ok so I was wondering how this can be achieved. I have tried putting all of the characteristics that i want to read and get notifications from into 2 separate queues. One for readCharacteristics and one for notifyCharacteristics. I call something like this(excuse not having actual code on my phone atm) gatt.readcharacteristic(readQueue.element()) then on the onCharacteristicRead callback I check if queue is not empty and call readCharacteristic method again. Reading works. The part that does not is getting the notifications. Since the onCharacteristicChanged callback is only called if a value actually changes and not after gatt.setCharacteristicNotification is complete I decided to check if the notifyqueue is not empty on the onDescriptWritr callback after writing the characteristics descriptor. So my question is why does reading the characteristics work in this manner but setting the notifications does not

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow exactly what you mean. Do you mean you have one queue for read characteristic operations and another queue for write descriptor operations? That won't work. You need to have one single queue for all operations on the same BluetoothGatt object, because the API only allows one outstanding operation at a time.

Comment: How can I have one queue when some of the characteristics operations  I need are descriptors so I can't populate same queue with both and even if I can how do I determine what to do literally check type?